# Serializer for creation of user profile in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to update the user profile in django rest framework
So i am able to create the user profile simultaneously with user creation using signals

Now i am trying to update the profile created:-

//models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    phone_regex=RegexValidator(regex = r'^[6-9]\d{9}$',message='please enter the correct phonenumber')

    #name_regex=RegexValidator(regex=r'/^[A-Za-z]+$/',message='Please enter the correct name')
    
    phone=models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],max_length=15,unique=True)
    
    date_joined=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined',auto_now_add=True)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login',auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_login=models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD='phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] 

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # There is an inherent relationship between the Profile and
    # User models. By creating a one-to-one relationship between the two, we
    # are formalizing this relationship. Every user will have one -- and only
    # one -- related Profile model.

    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Homme'),
        ('F', 'Femme'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # Each user profile will have a field where they can tell other users
    # something about themselves. This field will be empty when the user
    # creates their account, so we specify blank=True.
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True,validators=[validate_email],max_length=254,blank=True,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    dateofbirth=models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    Gender=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER,blank=True,null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(
        "Address",
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    address2 = models.CharField(
        "Society",
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        null=True

    )
    address3 = models.CharField(
        "Landmark",
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        null=True
        
    )
    zip_code = models.CharField(
        "ZIP / Postal code",
        max_length=12,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    city = models.CharField(
        "City",
        max_length=1024,
        default ="Gurugram",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    country = models.CharField(
        "Country",
        max_length=10,
        default="India",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    # In addition to the `bio` field, each user may have a profile image or
    # avatar. This field is not required and it may be blank.

    # A timestamp representing when this object was created.
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)

    # A timestamp representing when this object was last updated.
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.phone

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile_for_user(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

// Serializer.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields=("name",)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserProfileSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user', 'phone',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        profile = user_data.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile 
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            
            print("update function")
        
        #    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        #    print(profile_data)
            profile_data = validated_data.pop('user')
            profile = instance.profile
          #  print("profile is ",profile)

            print(profile_data.name)
            print("name in validation ",validated_data['name'], " type is ",print(type(validated_data)))

            instance.username = validated_data.get('name', instance.username)
            instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
            instance.save()
            print("name is ",instance.profile.name )
            #profile.Gender = validated_data['Gender'],
            #profile.email = validated_data['email'],
            #profile.dateofbirth=validated_data['dateofbirth'],
            #profile.address1=validated_data['address1'],
            ##profile.address2=validated_data['address2'],
            #profile.address3=validated_data['address3']
          #  print("1",profile)
            #print(profile.Gender)
            #print(profile.email)
            #print(profile.dateofbirth)
            profile.save()
            print("2",profile)
            print(profile.name)
            print("save done")

            return instance
```

//views.py

```
class ProfileCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
   
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("my print 0",request)
        header_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)
        print(header_token)
        access_token=header_token.split(' ')[1]
        status,user =validate_token(access_token)
        print(request.data)
        
        
        user_profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(
                    instance=user,
                data=request.data
        )
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(
                instance=user,
                data=request.data)
        print("my print 1",user_profile_serializer.is_valid())
        print("my print 2",user_serializer.is_valid())
        if user_profile_serializer.is_valid() and user_serializer.is_valid():
            user_profile_serializer.save()
            print("user_profile save done")
            user_serializer.save()
            print("user save done")

            return Response(
                    status=rt_status.HTTP_200_OK)
        # Combine errors from both serializers.
      #  errors = dict()
       # errors.update(user_profile_serializer.errors)
        #errors.update(user_serializer.errors)
        else:
            return Response(status=rt_status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        '''
        return Response(status=rt_status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        '''
```

Now the issue is  when i am hitting the api I am getting user_serializer.is_valid() as TRUE but False from UserProfile.
I feel there is some issue with my getting the  profile data.
But I am not able to understand how to resolve the issue .
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the user an Userprofile model instance?

Comment: yes , is the issue here?? i am trying with get_profile() for creating userprofile instance but it did'nt worked , any idea how should i go about it

Comment: what is the function and purpose of using signals if you could explain...